# Adding data to the list Dialog OnItemLongClick Listener

Tags: android, onitemlongclicklistener

With help of @raja I figured out that I need to update the data to the list. The reccomendation is to change line of the Dialog file:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

private View editText;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
    View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    fragment_monday.add(((TextView) editText).getText().toString());//here is your updated(or not updated) text
    dismiss();
}
}
```

precisely in onClick method to add fragment_monday.add to the line. 
Unfortunately when I add fragment_monday the error cannot be resolved or is not a field pops out.

I am unable to update data in list with my dialog file, I believe I don't call the list properly.
I can post additional code if necessary. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the recent logcat when the app crashes upon pressing confirm button in Dialog file:

```
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at         com.example.classorganizer.EditListItemDialog.onClick(EditListItemDialog.java:37)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-20 19:18:06.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1468):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Dialog doesn't know about `fragment_monday`

You could for example solve it by passing the list `fragment_monday` as a parameter in the constructor and declaring a field `fragment_monday`. Assuming that it is a list of Strings:

```
private List<String> fragment_monday;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context, List<String> fragment_monday) {
    super(context);
    this.fragment_monday = fragment_monday;
}
```

Side-note: I would rename "fragment_monday" because it is against the naming convention

Comment: when I do as suggested .add complains : - The method add(TextView) in the type List<TextView> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: when I do as suggested .add complains : - The method add(TextView) in the type List<TextView> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Then make it a list of Strings: `List<String>` ..will update answer

Comment: seems that there are no errors now. I will test it then

Comment: crashes when I confirm change in dialog file;/

Comment: Looks like NullPointerException on line 37. What is at that line?